# inflater.inflate gives nullpointer in Adapter getview method. Why?

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, listadapter

In my Android app I'm building my first custom adapter. I now run into a nullpointer at the line in which I inflate the convertView. See the code below:

```
private List<String> possibilitiesList = new ArrayList<String>();

public void setPossibilitiesList(List<String> possibilitiesList) {
    for (String possibility : possibilitiesList) {
        addItem(possibility);
    }
}

public void addItem (final String item) {
    possibilitiesList.add(item);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

private LayoutInflater inflater;

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    Log.e(this, "is called here!!");
    ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();
    convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_posibility, viewGroup, false);
    holder.possibilityTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text_possibility);
    holder.possibilityTitle.setText(possibilitiesList.get(position));
    return convertView;
}
```

and in my fragment I set the possibilitiesList as follows:

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.the_possibilities));
Log.e(this, new Integer(list.size()).toString()); // outputs 8
adapter.setPossibilitiesList(list);
```

I am 100% sure that the list_item_posibility.xml exists (Android Studio also highlights is as being existing), so I'm kinda lost on why this gives a nullpointer.

Does anybody know what I could be doing wrong here?

Comment: show us where you initialize inflater.

Comment: Is your `inflater` initialized ?

Comment: @Raghunandan - I added the initialization of the inflater to the question.

Comment: @kramer65 that is just a declaration not initialization

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`private LayoutInflater inflater;` is just declared not initialized

You need to pass the context to the constructor of adapter class and then use it to initialize inflater.

```
 new Yourcustomadapter(ActivityName.this); 
// pass the context here and other params
```

Then

```
 private LayoutInflater inflater; 
 public Yourcustomadapterr(Context context)
 {
      inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
 }
```

Also check this

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getContext()

Comment: or he can use the context of the ViewGroup

Comment: @blackbelt yes certainly can be used.

Comment: @Blundell i already mentioned in words yes i copied  `new CustomAdapter(ActivityName.this);` from your post. but as i said i already quoted "You need to pass the context to the constructor of adapter class and then use it to initialize inflater." before you answered. i only edited to make it complete.

Comment: Thanks for that, now it doesn't give me the nullpointer anymore. Just one more question; it now only shows the first item, even though the List I pass into it has 8 possibilities. Any ideas?

Comment: @kramer65 show how you pass the list to the adapter class  and where is it initialized

Comment: @kramer65 where is this called `setPossibilitiesList`. if you have items in list it will be displayed

Comment: @kramer65 and are you using baseadapter or arrayadapter

Comment: @Raghunandan - I extend BaseAdapter

Comment: @kramer65 post a new question with complete code. especially adapter code

Comment: @Raghunandan - Just did so here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21133692/why-does-my-android-listadapter-only-show-one-item

Answer (score 2):

Your inflater is null, you need to set it to a reference of an inflater

```
private final LayoutInflater inflater;

public CustomAdapter(LayoutInflater inflater) {
  this.inflater = inflater;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    Log.e("this", "is called here!!");
    ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();
    convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_posibility, viewGroup, false);
    holder.possibilityTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text_possibility);
    holder.possibilityTitle.setText(possibilitiesList.get(position));
    return convertView;
}
```

Then where you new up your adapter, either: (depending on where you init the adapter)

```
new CustomAdapter(LayoutInflater.from(this));
```

or

```
new CustomAdapter(LayoutInflater.from(context));
```

or

```
new CustomAdapter(getActivity().getLayoutInflater());
```

or

```
new CustomAdapter((LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE));
```