# Why does my Android ListAdapter only show one item?

Tags: java, android, listadapter

In my Android app I'm trying to build my very first custom listadapter. I now managed to get it to display one item, but unfortunately one item only where there are 8 in the list. My adapter looks like this:

```
public class PossibilitiesAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private AdapterCallbacks callbacks;
    private List<String> possibilitiesList = new ArrayList<String>();
    private LayoutInflater inflater;

    public PossibilitiesAdapter(Context context) {
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    public void setPossibilitiesList(List<String> possibilitiesList) {
        for (String possibility : possibilitiesList) {
            addItem(possibility);
        }
    }

    public void addItem (final String item) {
        possibilitiesList.add(item);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    private class ViewHolder {
        TextView possibilityTitle;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_posibility, viewGroup, false);
        holder.possibilityTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text_possibility);
        holder.possibilityTitle.setText(possibilitiesList.get(position));

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return possibilitiesList.size();
    }
    // And here are some more things like getItemId() and getItem()
}
```

and I set the possibilitiesList from my fragment like so:

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.the_possibilities));
Log.e(this, new Integer(list.size()).toString()); // Outputs 8, so there are enough in the array.
adapter.setPossibilitiesList(list);
```

My fragment_possibilities.xml looks like this:

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list_possibilities"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

and my list_item_possibility.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_possibility"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

So the problem is that it only displays the first item, and nothing more. Does anybody know what the problem is and how I can fix it?

Comment: where is your `getCount()`?

Comment: Post your `getCount()` method.

Comment: extends BaseFragment ?

Comment: @blackbelt - Excuse me, I added that line later but mistakenly copy-pasted it from the wrong document.. I corrected it.

Comment: @Raghunandan - I added the getCount() method as I have it in my file.

Comment: @kramer65 log the size in `getCount`. see what is the size.

Comment: any chance you're overriding notifyDataSetChanged in that class?

Comment: @Raghunandan - getCount() returns 8.. :S

Comment: @kramer65 then you should see the items also override `getItem` and `getItemId`. other than that i don't see any problem

Comment: @MikeIsrael - No I don't override notifyDataSetCahnged anywhere..

Comment: @kramer65 listview in a scrollview a big mistake. Never do that. also add data to your list in fragment and pass the list to the constructor and use it there. when you want to add new items add it to the list and call `notifyDataSetChanged` on your adapter

Comment: @Raghunandan - I first had it in a ListView, but neither a ScrollView or a ListView works out.

Comment: @kramer65 as i said add items to list in fragment. pass the list to the constructor of adapter class. use it there. secondly listview in scorllview is wrong. why? check this http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html. i am pretty sure it will work. google for an example

Comment: @kramer65 can you add the whole fragment_possibilities.xml?  Guessing the issue is from missing information.

Comment: @MikeIsrael - You were right. The missing information is from the xml from the activity in which the fragment is loaded. That turned out to be a scrollview after all.. :S

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you nesting your list inside a ScrollView? It would be a typically behaving that it only shows one item. Try to avoid it o use the following method.

```
/**
 * read all adapter views and calculate total length
 *
 * @param listView
 */
public static void setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(ListView listView) {
    ListAdapter listAdapter = listView.getAdapter();
    if (listAdapter == null) {
        return;
    }

    int totalHeight = 0;
    int desiredWidth = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(listView.getWidth(), MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
    for (int i = 0; i < listAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
        View listItem = listAdapter.getView(i, null, listView);
        listItem.measure(desiredWidth, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
        totalHeight += listItem.getMeasuredHeight();
    }

    setListViewHeight(listView, totalHeight);
}

/**
 * set listview height
 *
 * @param listView
 * @param height
 */
public static void setListViewHeight(ListView listView, int height) {
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = listView.getLayoutParams();
    params.height = height + (listView.getDividerHeight() * (listView.getAdapter().getCount() - 1));
    listView.setLayoutParams(params);
    listView.requestLayout();
}
```

No that will not work, as I said, you cant put a ListView Inside a ScrollView.

Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list_possibilities"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I added my xml files to my question. As far as I can see they're pretty basic and correct. Can you see anything wrong in there?

Comment: Yes it wrong, change your xml and mark my answer as solved please :)

Comment: I had your suggested xml before, but that didn't work. I added it again, but still no more than 1 result in the list.

Comment: In the end you turned out to be right after all. I nested the fragment (a listview) inside an xml from the activity, which turned out to be a scrollview. Stupid me. Thanks for all the energy!

Answer (score 1):

your getView Method is implemented wrong, more precisely the view holder pattern.
im guessing you see the right amount of entries but all with same content

try this:

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    ViewHolder holder = null;
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_posibility, viewGroup, false);
        holder = new Holder();
        holder.possibilityTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text_possibility);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
    }

    holder.possibilityTitle.setText(possibilitiesList.get(position));

    return convertView;
}
```

and somehow i think your setPossibilitesMethod seems odd. id probably use something like this

```
public void setPossibilitiesList(List<String> possibilitiesList) {
    this.possibilitiesList = possibilitiesList;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public void addItem (final String item) {
    possibilitiesList.add(item);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public void addItems (List<String> possibilitiesList) {
    this.possibilitiesList.addAll(possibilitiesList);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

and you can shorten the code for the retrieval of the inflaterService like this:

```
public PossibilitiesAdapter(Context context) {
    inflater = LayoutInflater.fromContext(context);
}
```

In addition you dont have to cast it

**updated**

```
@Override
public int getCount(){
    for (String possibility : this.possibilities){
        System.out.println(possibility);
    }
    int size = this.possibilities();
    System.out.println("getCount: " + size);
    return size;
}
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but it leads to a nullpointer on this line: holder.possibilityTitle.setText(possibilitiesList.get(position));

Comment: I tried this, but to no avail. Also, I don't see 8 times the same content, but just the first item once. Would you have any other ideas?

Comment: put breakpoints in each method , in get count , in add element and tell us the results

Comment: @kramer65 next logical step seems to exchange you getCount Method for the one i just added

Answer (score 1):

Change the method addItem and remove notify from there , add notify after the for in the metghod setList

Comment: This would not offer a way to dynamically change data anymore.

Comment: Then the notify data changed should not be called after each item !!! It shoulb be callled like this     public void setPossibilitiesList(List<String> possibilitiesList) {
        for (String possibility : possibilitiesList) {
            addItem(possibility);
        } Notify Here and remove notify from addItem method
    }

Comment: I would not recommend to instantiate a new adapter each time the data changes.

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but unfortunately to no avail. I still get only the first string to display.

Answer (score 1):

The most possible case is you are getting `possibilitiesList.size()` as **1** when you execute `getCount()` method. Print a log to check the value.

Comment: Unfortunately that's not the case; a `Log.e(this, newInteger(getCount()).toString);` returns 8.

Comment: I would recomment you to put the log inside getCount() method. Since the sixe may by 1 when that method is called by the framework. I also could think that there may be empty string in the rest 7 items in possibilitiesList which could also make the textview invisible.

Comment: I did that, but to no avail; it still displays 8

Comment: And I just looped over the possibilitiesList from within the adapter and printed all the strings in it, and it displays all strings correctly.. :S

Comment: Can you change from BaseAdapter to ArrayAdapter and try.

Comment: @NareshR what difference would that make